# Can't use C# .NET 6 PriorityQueue in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-6.0, priority-queue

I'm trying to use `PriorityQueue` in Unity with C#. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2?view=net-6.0) says that it's supported in .NET 6 in namespace `System.Collections.Generic`.

I've tried:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class Test : Monobehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        var queue = new PriorityQueue<int, int>();
    }
}
```

But an error is thrown back:

> ```
> The type or namespace name 'PriorityQueue<,>' could not be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> [Assembly-CSharp]
> ```

I've checked the .NET version within VS Code:
[image]

Why doesn't it work in Unity?

Comment: What is the target framework version in the project file? Just running `dotnet` from a prompt doesn't prove much.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I found this in the `.csproj` file `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>`. This is the problem?

Comment: Well yes, it's obviously targeting .NET 4.7.1, and given the name of that element this is an old-style `.csproj`, not the new-style (that uses `TargetFramework` and `TargetFrameworks`, and is a lot shorter besides). I'm not sure Unity even has support for .NET Core (yet), which 6 is, but that's another question.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm currently using Unity 2020.3, a bit behind now, not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: @JeroenMostert just search around in [Unity doc 2020.3](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html) a bit, said that .NET standard 2.0 and .NET 4.x are supported. Yeah... Seems like even [Unity 2022.1 doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.1/Documentation/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html) said the same thing, so...

Comment: Fortunately priority queues are not rocket science (if that's the only thing you're going for in terms of .NET 6); compatible implementations should be easy to find. Sufficiently unimportant queues that aren't crucially dependent on performance can even be faked with other data structures (like a `SortedList` or `SortedDictionary` using a tuple that includes the priority and an ID for uniqueness, with only the priority used for sorting through a custom comparer).

Comment: I have the same issue. I checked visual studio installer and know .NET 6 is installed. Project target framework is .NET Framework 4.8. I'm also just using this in a console application in visual studio, nothing special like unity involved.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The version reported by `dotnet` is completely unrelated to Unity's C#/.NET version ([at least until Unity finally migrates from Mono](https://blog.unity.com/technology/unity-and-net-whats-next)). [While the language supported is almost equal to C# 9.0](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html), the actual *library* that is used is a loose superset of what Mono provides, and [actually is roughly equal to .NET Framework 4.8/.NET Standard 2.0 ATM](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/); since neither of those has `PriorityQueue`, it's not available. You can either:

- wait for the transition to .NET 6/7 happen (be aware it may take a couple of years :),
- use a 3rd party implementation,
- implement it yourself,
- [copy-paste the code from the official source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/PriorityQueue.cs)
  (minor tweaks will be required for it to work) or
- use this [direct port from official C# lib](https://github.com/FyiurAmron/PriorityQueue/blob/main/PriorityQueue.cs)
  (single-file drop-in, ported by me, open source, no string attached).

Comment: Yeah, I have imported C5 and used their `IntervalHeap` since then, pretty fine!