# How do I distribute a value across a list of integers, with a priority to fill the integers to a soft-cap first

Tags: c#, math

I am trying to solve the concept of filling every item in a list until every item has reached a ceiling. Once every item has reached a ceiling/limit any remaining excess values is then distributed once more starting from the first item of the list. Examples after the current breakdown.

I believe I have a solution for the first component of the problem, distributing values - however I am unsure of the solution to dealing with excess values.

A detailed example:

> I have a list of boxes (`10` boxes) and a value of `33` products, I
> want to distribute the products one at a time across these boxes until
> a limit ceiling for each box is set (`5` products). Every box must be
> filled to `5` before I pick my first box again and start one at a time
> to add the remaining excess.

In the table below, `init` is the pre-existing values stored in each box. The next columns show distribution across the boxes for values of `25`,`33`, and finally `40`. In `40` you can see more clearly how priority of filling in the emptiest boxes preceeds eventually filling every other box in.

| init | 25 | 33 | 40 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
| 0 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| -1 | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 0 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

My current logic is this:

```cs
class Box
{
    public float amount;
}

public static void Init()
{
    // Create a list of boxes.

    List<Box> boxes = new List<Box>
    {
        // Add boxes to the list.
        new Box() { amount = 2 },
        new Box() { amount = 1 },
        new Box() { amount = 2 },
        new Box() { amount = 0 },
        new Box() { amount = -1 },
        new Box() { amount = 2 },
        new Box() { amount = 3 },
        new Box() { amount = 0 },
        new Box() { amount = 2 },
        new Box() { amount = 1 }
    };

    Distribute(boxes, 25, 2);

}

static void Distribute(List<Box> boxes, float totalValue, float maxDistribution)
{
    float ceiling = 5; //The "soft limit" for each box.

    List<Box> currentBoxes = boxes;
    List<Box> criticalBoxes = new List<Box>();

    int distribution = (int)(totalValue / maxDistribution); //amount of times needed for even distribution.
    int currentBoxIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < distribution; i++)
    {

        //If we have room, add distribution, else move to a "at capacity list"
        if (currentBoxes[currentBoxIndex].amount + maxDistribution < ceiling)
        {
            currentBoxes[currentBoxIndex].amount += maxDistribution; //Distribute the maximum allowed per loop
        } else
        {
            criticalBoxes.Add(currentBoxes[currentBoxIndex]);
            currentBoxes.RemoveAt(currentBoxIndex);
        }

        //Status of loop.
        if(currentBoxIndex == currentBoxes.Count)
        {
            currentBoxIndex = 0;
        } else
        {
            currentBoxIndex++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Since excess is always < boxCount, can't you just add a for-loop after your current loop, with loop count equal to excess, and going through your list of boxes by index, adding one each time?

Comment: Your logic seems wonky. There are 10 boxes, and 25 items to distribute but all boxes have gained only 2 items

Comment: Wouldn't this be solved by simply ignoring the cap and instead just always adding one item to the box with the fewest items in it, until you have no more items to distribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems binary; either the amount you have to distribute will completely fill boxes (with/out overspill) or it won't. If it will, then start from them all full and distribute the overspill, otherwise, distribute to a cap

```
int distrib = 40;
int cap = 5;
int space = boxes.Sum(b => cap - b.Amount);
int overspill = distrib - space;

if(overspill >= 0){

  boxes.ForEach(b => b.Amount = cap + overspill / boxes.Count);
  distrib = overspill % boxes.Count;
  cap = int.MaxValue;
}


for(int x= 0; x < distrib;){
  var b = boxes[x%boxes.Count];
  if(b.Amount >= cap)
    continue;
  boxes[x%boxes.Count].Amount++;
  x++;
}
```

If instead you want a logic of prioritizing the emptiest boxes, it gets simpler with MinBy (.net6 or MoreLinq)

```
int distrib = 25;
while(distrib-- > 0)
  boxes.MinBy(b => b.Amount).Amount++;
```

In older .net that's `boxes.First(b => b.Amount == boxes.Min(b2 => b2.Amount) ).Amount++;`

There's plenty of scope for optimizing and tweaking this, but how much it's worth the effort depends on how much of a hot spot it is

Comment: The first example indeed looks to work, unfortunately my .net doesn't support `MinBy` so I'm looking into the "older" example, whats the logic of "B2"

Comment: The B2 was a typo of b2, sorry - iPhone autocorrect of a vitamin maybe :). In very old .net (framework 472) it would complain if you use the same alias inside an inner lambda (`b` is used for the `First` so you'd get a "variable is already defined" if you try and use it again for the `Min`)..If you want MaxBy in an older framework, you can install the MoreLinq library

Comment: It's worth noting that the first loop approach does a "round robin distribute" whereas "prioritize empty buckets" strategy fills the emptiest buckets first, then when the emptiest bucket comes up to the level of the next emptiest they fill alternately.. This mean in your examples your -1 bucket would fill to 0, then the three 0s would fill to 1, then the five 1s would fill to 2... It's a bit like rising sea levels with mountains poking out rather than growing the mountains and the valleys up to a cap of mountain height (flat topped mountains)

Comment: Accepting as answer. Out of curiosity, is it possible to use this approach "inverted", so as to reduce across the list evenly until all points are 0, THEN go into the negatives?

Comment: You want to take from the most well stocked box first? Sure.. `while(some_count_of_how_many_to_take-- > 0) boxes.MaxBy(b => b.Amount).Amount--;`

Comment: If you're round robin'ing a decrement it's slightly tweaked logic but more or less the same; does the sum of all stock satisfy the demand? No, then take everything to 0, reduce the demand by the sum of stock, and then decrement into negatives in order to satisfy. Yes, then pay the demand out of the stock, skipping any that are at or below 0 rather than at or above cap. Mostly you should be able to get that algo from what is there but flipping every increment to a decrement.. I'll see if it can be reworked to provide optional direction

Answer (score 1):

I think this is close:

```
List<Box> boxes = new List<Box>
{
    // Add boxes to the list.
    new Box() { amount = 2 },
    new Box() { amount = 1 },
    new Box() { amount = 2 },
    new Box() { amount = 0 },
    new Box() { amount = -1 },
    new Box() { amount = 2 },
    new Box() { amount = 3 },
    new Box() { amount = 0 },
    new Box() { amount = 2 },
    new Box() { amount = 1 }
};

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", boxes.Select(b => b.amount)));

var sorted = boxes.OrderBy(b => b.amount < 5f ? int.MinValue : b.amount).ToList();

while (boxes.Sum(b => b.amount) < 52f)
{
    var box = sorted.First();
    sorted.RemoveAt(0);
    box.amount += 1.0f;
    sorted = sorted.Append(box).OrderBy(b => b.amount < 5f ? int.MinValue : b.amount).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", boxes.Select(b => b.amount)));
}
```

That gives me:

```
2, 1, 2, 0, -1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1
3, 1, 2, 0, -1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1
3, 2, 2, 0, -1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1
3, 2, 3, 0, -1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1
3, 2, 3, 1, -1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1
3, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1
3, 2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 2, 1
3, 2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 4, 0, 2, 1
3, 2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1
3, 2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1
3, 2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2
4, 2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2
4, 3, 3, 1, 0, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2
4, 3, 4, 1, 0, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2
4, 3, 4, 2, 0, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2
4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2
4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2
4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2
4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2
4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2
4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3
5, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3
5, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3
5, 4, 5, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3
5, 4, 5, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3
5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3
5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 5, 5, 2, 4, 3
5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3
5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3
5, 4, 5, 3, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4
5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4
5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4
5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4
5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4
5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5
5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5
5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5
5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5
6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5
```

Comment: This looks like an elegant solution unfortunately `PriorityQueue` is not available to me natively in this case. Is this a requirement?

Comment: @KeiranLovett - No, it's not. We're dealing with software. You can use whatever collection you like that can be sorted.

Comment: I appreciate your answer truly and believe it to be a worthy answer. However sometimes there are restrictions to versions on some tools. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70568157/cant-use-priority-queue-in-c-sharp-net-6

Comment: @KeiranLovett - Did you notice that I have removed the `PriorityQueue`?